# Need help turning a Bigquery UNNESTED ARRAY into a single row

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, unnest

I have an UNNESTED ARRAY with 5 rows. I want to turn this flatted ARRAY into a wide single row.

| Row | id | fpe.graduate | fpe.type | fpe.institution | fpe.AttenedanceYear | fpe.degree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1003009358 | TRUE | Senior | HighschoolC | 2013 | Diploma |
| 2 | 1003009358 | FALSE | Freshman | HighschoolB | 2010 | null |
| 3 | 1003009358 | FALSE | Freshman | HighschoolA | 2009 | null |
| 4 | 1003009358 | FALSE | Junior | HighschoolC | 2012 | null |
| 5 | 1003009358 | FALSE | Sophmore | HighschoolC | 2011 | null |

INTO

| Row | id | fpe.graduate_1 | fpe.type_1 | fpe.institution_1 | fpe.AttenedanceYear_1 | fpe.degree_1 | fpe.graduate_2 | fpe.type_2 | fpe.institution_2 | fpe.AttenedanceYear_2 | fpe.degree_2 | fpe.graduate_3 | fpe.type_3 | fpe.institution_3 | fpe.AttenedanceYear_3 | fpe.degree_3 | fpe.graduate_4 | fpe.type_4 | fpe.institution_4 | fpe.AttenedanceYear_4 | fpe.degree_4 | fpe.graduate_5 | fpe.type_5 | fpe.institution_5 | fpe.AttenedanceYear_5 | fpe.degree_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1003009358 | TRUE | Senior | HighschoolC | 2013 | Diploma | FALSE | Freshman | HighschoolB | 2010 | null | FALSE | Freshman | HighschoolA | 2009 | null | FALSE | Junior | HighschoolC | 2012 | null | FALSE | Sophmore | HighschoolC | 2011 | null |

I do not want to pivot the data, as that will create more havoc. Instead, take the existing column headers and add a [column_name]UNDERSCORE(next incremental number).

Comment: `I do not want to pivot the data` --> but your expected result is a pivoted form of original data.  You mean you don't want to use `PIVOT` query ?

Comment: you could use an unwelding case or if statement to do this, though pivot seems the logical choice.